# How to get value from element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

How can I get the value from this element:

```html
<div time="1582408800000" title="" class="day toMonth  valid real-today checked first-date-selected">23</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```js
//web.getAttribute('//div[@class="day toMonth  valid real-today"]', div)

var bsaleDate = web.getValue('//div[@class="day toMonth  valid real-today"]');
```

I'm trying to get the `23` as a value and insert it into a variable.
I am using Oxygen IDE which is based on JavaScript.

Comment: `<div>` elements don't have a "value".  You're looking for `.textContent` probably.

Comment: I don’t think `time` is a valid attribute on a div

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DOM` selector to select the element and then get the content.

Note that `div` element doesn't has the `value attribute`, `Div` element could hold html or text content.

To get the `html` content we could use `innerHTML` attribute.
And to get text we could use `textContent` attribute

I am using `document.querySelector` to select the element with the help of `css` selector.

```js
(function() {
    let ele = document.querySelector('.first-date-selected');
    console.log(ele.textContent);
})()
```

```html
<div time="1582408800000" title="" class="day toMonth  valid real-today checked first-date-selected">23</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the getElementsByClassName method to get all the elements of specific class.

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("day");

IF you want to Get all elements with "day toMonth  valid real-today checked first-date-selected" classes, you can just use below statement.

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("day toMonth  valid real-today checked first-date-selected");

alert(x[0].innerText);

Hope this could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

by value if you meant '23' is what you wanted. Then you can use **getText()**.